# How to detect when cordova.js has finished processing

Tags: cordova

I've started working on a PhoneGap app for the first time and I'd like to know how to detect when the code in **cordova.js** has finished processing. I have searched quite a bit but haven't come across such a simple answer so I'm wondering if I'm actually searching correctly.

When I test the app in a browser, for example, the PhoneGap splash page appears and there is a pause before it disappears. When I remove the loading of **cordova.js** this does not happen, obviously. However, I do want to use **cordova.js**.

So, the question is how do I detect when that pause is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Determine for how much time your splash screen is showing by looking at the value of `SplashScreenDelay` in `config.xml`
must be something like flowing

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

if preference is not there in `config.xml`, you can add it.
once you know the `SplashScreenDelay`
add `setTimeOut` for that time period in your `deviceready` event
like following

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    console.log("Cordova/device is ready");
    //do further tasks.
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    setTimeOut(onDeviceReady,3000) // 3000 is ms set in preference earlier in config.xml
    }, false);
```

Comment: I already have that it place but the callback gets called when the splash screen appears and not after it disappears.

Comment: in that case check your confing.xml for `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />` , value is 3000 milliseconds so splash screen will appear for 3 seconds. you can wrap your function around with `setTimeOut(function(){ },3000)`. That should do it.

Comment: That seems to be the cause of the delay. I've had a look at `confing.xml` but it doesn't contain that preference though. I'll see where else it could be set. If you have any ideas please let me know and thanks for the help so far.

Comment: if splash-screen functionality is achieved by the [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen) then that `<preference>` should be there in config. if splash-screen is achieved using js then it will be different scenario.
And Happy to help at any time.

Comment: I just added `<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />` to **confing.xml** and that worked. If you'd like to add those details in your answer I'll mark it as answered as it was very helpful.

Comment: @camden_kid added :)

Comment: One last question, is there a callback for when the splash screen is removed or do you just have to set a time out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112513/discussion-between-arpit-vasani-and-camden-kid).